# php array merge recursive with same array values and create combinations

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, combinations

Hello i am new in php and I just stuck in brainstorming array, I have below php array

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 12
                [11] => 15
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 12
                [11] => 16
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 9
                [11] => 15
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 9
                [11] => 15
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 9
                [11] => 16
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 13
                [11] => 15
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 13
                [11] => 16
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 12
                [11] => 15
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [1] => 3
                [2] => 12
                [11] => 16
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 9
                [11] => 16
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 13
                [11] => 15
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 13
                [11] => 16
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 12
                [11] => 15
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [1] => 4
                [2] => 12
                [11] => 16
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 9
                [11] => 15
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [1] => 5
                [2] => 13
                [11] => 16
            )

    )
```

And I want below out put

```
[0]=> Array
(
    [5]=> Array
    (
        [12]=> Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
        )
        [9]=> Array
        (
            [0] => 15
        )
        [13]=> Array
        (
            [0] => 16
        )
    )
    [4]=> Array
    (
        [9]=> Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
        )
        [13]=> Array
        (
            [0] => 16
        )
        [12]=> Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
        )
    )
    [3]=> Array
    (
        [9]=> Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16 
        )
        [13]=> Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16
        )
        [12]=> Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 16

        )
    )
)
```

Sorry out put not much clear but I want check each array first common value e.g 5,4, and 3 then based on these value traverse though each value and create tree array
As Example simple i want each arrays first element and then recursively array check values and create new
Example have just 3 level but i want recursive n-level and , help would be Appreciate.

Comment: Your question is at least too broad without an attempt...

Comment: Do you have a smaller example and output array? Would you also provide the methodology for creating your output array? It's not obvious from your example.

Comment: @bassxzero i want each array first element for eg if you see 5,4 and 3 are common so based on that again loop wise check each element again and again find common under 5,4 and 3 and construct array..

Comment: @FirstOne, i tried construct array using array_shift and then based on first element tried to check again each element but its work only 2 level so i example 3 level array and out put..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly as the samples are not explained clearly but I somehow was able to print the desired output. Explanations given thru comments

```
// I just simplified your given array
$input[0] = array(
    [1 => 5, 2 => 12, 11 => 15],
    [1 => 5, 2 => 12, 11 => 16],
    [1 => 4, 2 =>  9, 11 => 15],
    [1 => 3, 2 =>  9, 11 => 15],
    [1 => 3, 2 =>  9, 11 => 16],
    [1 => 3, 2 => 13, 11 => 15],
    [1 => 3, 2 => 13, 11 => 16],
    [1 => 3, 2 => 12, 11 => 15],
    [1 => 3, 2 => 12, 11 => 16],
    [1 => 4, 2 =>  9, 11 => 16],
    [1 => 4, 2 => 13, 11 => 15],
    [1 => 4, 2 => 13, 11 => 16],
    [1 => 4, 2 => 12, 11 => 15],
    [1 => 4, 2 => 12, 11 => 16],
    [1 => 5, 2 =>  9, 11 => 15],
    [1 => 5, 2 => 13, 11 => 16]
);

// Declare new output array
$output[0] = [];

// Loop thru each array inside $input[0] array
foreach($input[0] as $key => $value) {

    // Set each array value to variables
    $one = $value[1];
    $two = $value[2];
    $eleven = $value[11];

    // Check if $one key already exist, create if not
    if (!isset($output[0][$one])) {
            $output[0][$one] = [];
    }

    // Check if $two key already exist, create if not
    if (!isset($output[$one][$two])) {
            $output[0][$one][$two] = [];
    }

    // push each $eleven
    $output[0][$one][$two][] = $eleven;
};

// Prints output array
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Hi @erwin Thanks for help its exact what i want :) but code is limited to three values.. array might have 4 values or more values..

Comment: You mean the input array could have 4 keys/values? Can you give example with let's say 4 values? :)

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate situations where you have multiple first-level elements, use a loop.  Use another loop to iterate each entry.  You can even use array destructuring inside the nested `foreach()` to declare variables.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SYJfi))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($input as $key => $array) {
    foreach ($array as [1 => $one, 2 => $two, 11 => $eleven]) {
        $result[$key][$one][$two][] = $eleven;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

There is no need to declare/assign parent keys to append data into them.  There are deliberately no conditions in my snippet.